# Lightweight SQL database which doesn't require installation

Tags: sql, .net, database, ms-access

Could you recommend a lightweight SQL database which doesn't require installation on a client computer to work and could be accessed easily from .NET application? Only basic SQL capabilities are needed.

Now I am using Access database in simple projects and distribute .MDB and .EXE files together. Looking for any alternatives.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by lightweight. Easy on RAM? Or lighter db file? Or lighter connector to connect to db? Or fewer files over all? I'll give a comparison of what I know:

```
                    no of files    cumulative size of files    db size

Firebird 2.5             5                6.82 MB               250 KB

SqlServerCe 4            7                2.08 MB               64 KB

Sqlite 3.7.11.0          1                0.83 MB               15 KB

VistaDb 4.3.3.34         1                1.04 MB               48 KB

no of files - includes the .net connector and excludes the db file
```

The dbs are of 1 table with 2 columns and 2 rows. Take the db size with a pinch of salt as dbs could grow differently with further use. For instance `SqlServerCe` though initially was at 64 KB, it didn't grow at all after adding a few hundred records, while `VistaDb` grew easily from 48 to 72 to 140 KB. SQLite was the best in that regard which started from the lowest and grew linearly.

Few anecdotes: I had better performance using SqlServerCe with the factory settings which means its the easiest to get kick started without any configuration, while I found Firebird little bit harder to get it started due to lack of online materials. Firebird as I could read had widest standard sql compliance. While VistaDb is written in fully managed C# which means it can be merged with your application's assembly to have one single file, it seemed slowest to me. Of all, considering performance, ease and size I chose SQLite. SqlServerCe would be my second choice.

In short each has its pluses and minuses. Again, take my rant with a pinch of salt, its just my personal experience.

Answer (score 26):

Check [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), it's a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine.

It has many [wrappers](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWrappers) for .NET

Answer (score 4):

Howabout SQL Server 3.5/2008 Compact Edition?  A neat embedded version of SQL Server.

http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx

Works pretty nice with .NET, and of course all your regular SQL Server tools and scripts work fine.

Comment: Tried it today. Unfortunately it doesn't support views as Access JET engine does but thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah to get more fullfledged SQL features would require stepping up to Express and much more complex installation.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/8/8/e8859616-e95d-41fe-9f81-ff88388d772b/SQLServer%202008CompareComapctExpress.pdf

Has a detailed comparison of the two products.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at VistaDB if you are writing in .NET.  It is 100% managed code, contains true referential integrity, tsql stored procs, clr procs, and much more in a single assembly you can xcopy deploy.

VistaDB runs in shared hosting asp.net sites under medium trust, and in active directory domains as guest (no local permissions) as well.

There are no registry or other configuration settings required on the machine you deploy the engine on, and the runtime is royalty free.

32/64 bit support is included in the single assembly.  Mixed mode engines with unmanaged code generally require you to ship more than 1 version of the unmanaged code to support 32 and 64 bit, or to recompile for specific CPU targets.

See the [Advantages of VistaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273/what-are-the-advantages-of-vistadb) SO thread for more information.

http://www.vistadb.net

Answer (score 3):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is great.

Also check out [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) embedded. It might be a better option if multiple users need to access the database in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can store your data as JSON files.  If you need it to be stand-alone, there are dll solutions such as [IODB](http://www.iodb.ca) and [LiteDB](http://www.litedb.org)

Answer (score 2):

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) will be what you're after