# Which datastore (database) should be used for Spring-boot REST API application with AZURE

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, database-design, azure-sql-database, microservices

There are may blog available around this but still not getting exactly what is needed.

I am trying to write a REST API with Spring Boot and store data in database. Here the database structure may change (new tables can get introduced or some existing names may get renamed).

Which DB can be used so that there would be minimal code changes needed both at java side and DB side.

What could be a best design approach in this scenario considering technology stack as Spring Boot and Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please visualize about your persistent storage? Why Azure Only? Refine question.

e.g. H2 database with Spring Boot is the most memory efficient.
see [Lightest Database to be packed with an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431546/lightest-database-to-be-packed-with-an-application)

About Minimal code changes - I'd go with one of the ORM - JPA(or Hibernate). So will only need to maintain @Entity class on java side.

Don't forget - minimal changes still need to be addressed at database & Java side.